# Why is the preposition treated as the head of a prepositional phrase?

Tags: syntax, prepositions

What are the theoretical reasons for treating the preposition as the head of a prepositional phrase? (Noun as head of NP sounds fine intuitively, but the same does not apply to prepositions in prepositional phrases. I have never seen a theoretical justification for this treatment.)

Comment: If the head of an NP is a noun, and the head of an AdjP is an adjective , and the head of an AdvP is an adverb, and so on, why shouldn't a preposition be the head of a PP?

Comment: That does introduce a rather different concept of "head" -- in an NP or VP, one can refer to the N or V alone, and it defines the constituent. In a PP, the important word is the NP object, not the preposition. PPs act like NPs in many ways and calling them something different doesn't change that. Headship is another weak point of this theory.

Comment: And we can equally refer to the P alone, which defines the phrase. Prepositions take a wide range of complement types comparable to that of verbs: "I was talking to _a friend_" (NP Object); "I regard her as _a friend_" (predicative); "I stayed until _after lunch_" (PP) ; "It won't last for _long_" (AdvP); "I left because _I was tired_" (clause). We could hardly claim that all those PP resemble NPs. The important word is the prep, since that is that word that takes the dependents in the same way as the head does in other categories.

Comment: jlawler has hit the nail on the head. Take out the adnominal elements (excluding articles) and you still have a viable NP. "I felt the overpowering heat that emanated from the alien spaceship" > "I felt the heat". But take out the other elements of a prepositional phrase and you mostly get nonsense. "I was talking to" (really?), "I regard her as" (?), "I stayed until" (?), "It won't last for" (?), "I left because" (?). The prepositions are an element shared by all prepositional phrases, but without the rest of the phrase prepositions are mostly just flotsam.

Comment: "That" is a meaningless subordinator, but preps have a semantic content, and hence make a contribution to the meaning of the PP.

Answer (score 7):

The head of a phrase ought to affect the category of that phrase.  In turn, we can estimate whether phrases are of different categories by examining facts of verb subcategorization. Paradigms like

```
   He fell into the hole
  *He fell the hole.
```

suggest that "into the hole" and "the hole" are of different categories, which will be true if the preposition "into" is the head of the complement of "fell", but not necessarily otherwise.

Comment: Answer makes sense. The 'head' of a 'phrase' is the word that determines the syntactic category of the phrase. OK. But this sounds like a labelling exercise. NPs are endocentric whereas PPs are not. Quite a difference. Prepositions also somehow strike me as a superficial phenomenon. Take 'I was there in June' vs 'I was there until June', both with PPs (except in journalism), but 'I was there last June' vs 'I was there until last June' or 'I was there yesterday' vs 'I was there until yesterday'. It may be linguistically relevant to signal PPs vs non-PPs, but the distinctions seem skin deep.

Comment: In logical notation, prepositions are usually ignored, especially if they're governed by the verb as transitivizers, like the _at_ in _look at_ or the _to_ in _listen to_. Logically, those are transitive verbs; syntactically, they're not even constituents. But logic is strong enough to make idioms -- _Lookit!_

Comment: @jlawler, If "look at" and "listen to" are not constituents, how come they can be passivized or gapped as though they were verbs?

Comment: Because the morphology has run them together to become new complex verbs. That's how new constituents come about. It also means that they have two constituent structures simultaneously; either can be chosen. As the OP suggests this is a labelling exercise. Me, I don't believe in heads as a formal category, just a loose associative term.

Comment: "Head" is not a category; it's a function term. Complex verbs? The verbs in "look at" and "listen to" are 'prepositional verbs, i.e. the prep is specified by the verb.

Comment: As suggested, a labelling exercise.

Comment: @Bathrobe - why did you say PPs are not endocentric?  "in [the office]" is a PP with or without the NP -- that's endocentric.  Calling "A big book" an NP may seem endocentric, but calling it a DP is just as endocentric (since 'a' means 'one', and changing the phrase to "one" keeps it a DP [without forcing *pronoun* onto a determiner]  -- changing to "book" keeps it an NP but is defective, and note that the noun's plurality is a determiner function).

Comment: @Bathrobe - re. "In June" vs "until June", the preposition is hardly superficial, since it specifies two non-intersecting sets.

Comment: How many languages do you actually know, aml? You are playing around with English-centred formalisms. Does it work for other languages?

Answer (score 0):

Heads are useful for understanding deep structure, but they can be hard to identify in surface structure.

- Heads are closed-class words -- they are difficult to coin.
- Heads have default values, which can often be elided if doing so will not confuse the delineation of other phrases.
- Languages are pretty consistent about whether heads append to the beginning or end of phrases.

That said, nouns would not be the heads of phrases.  The head of an NP would be a quantifier, but it can be omitted if the noun is proper, or the quantity is '[all]', or the quantity has been mentioned (definite). That is why some theories use DP instead of NP (and determiners don't have to also be pronouns).

Temporal nouns used adverbially don't need a head (preposition) because it can be assumed ('Sunday' = '[at] Sunday' = 'on Sunday') or it has already been grafted onto the noun ('today').

Verbs are headed by auxiliary verbs, unless those are omitted for the default (habitual/present tense or irregular verbs) or have been morphed onto the verb (regular past tense).

Comment: That is a GG explanation in terms of tree diagrams, and, I would suggest, potentially just an artifact of the theory. What I asked for was a theoretical justification for the notion that prepositions head PPs. Also, how cross-linguistically relevant is the PP? Are all languages supposed to have them?

Comment: Whether to call them 'heads' or 'tails' is just an artifact, but the theoretical justification is that lexical words are stored only once, in a dictionary, and all storage of event memory is done only with heads (function words) that link (to other heads or finally to the lexical dictionary).  The theory (not yet a "theorum" per Richard Dawkins) says that the closed-class distinction is important and will be observed in the brain. ...

Comment: I don't know whether a 'prep' is the only way to express a *relation between objects*, but I suspect that the chaining of heads ("would have been on") may be an artifact of the abstract 'tree' rather than a feature of the concrete 'net'.

Comment: The additional explanation is helpful and answers my question. Your disclaimers are important, though, particularly the fact that the theory assumes the function vs lexical distinction is observed in the brain. One could uncharitably assume that this is more a pious hope than a proven fact.

Comment: Indeed -- Information entropy says we won't find overly redundant data in the brain, but whether the data is overt and orthogonal, or covertly hidden in layers, (or something spookier), is as yet unknown.

Comment: From your comment (2 days ago), the basic framework of grammar is something like: "Something definite or indefinite etc." "in a certain time or mode" "something definite or indefinite etc." "oriented to a certain location or thing"...., with lexical content filled in later. Two things occur to me: Isn't this an a priori idealisation? and Is a tree structure really the right way to capture this? Crosslinguistically it looks arbitrary/messy --ready to 'blow out' again if it commits to capturing too much (evidentiality, attitudinal markers, etc., etc.).

Comment: A priori by necessity; idealized because comprehensive and efficient; a net (trees are single sentences reconstructed from speech, a serial channel); open framework (no links until needed); [in]definite is for communication, not memory; objects and adverbials are all optional; nuance/context 'markers' would hurt any system (use adverbials?);  I apologize that my words painted such a bad picture for you.

Comment: No, your words didn't paint a bad picture; they helped make sense of it. I still don't understand why the Cambridge Grammar adopts prepositions as head of the PP since it is not GG. As for the rest, much is prioritising formalism over facts ('a priori by necessity' doesn't make sense for any theory; 'idealised' still needs to be grounded in reality; 'trees are reconstructed from speech', and financial derivatives are based on underlying physical wealth, look where that got us; nuance and context are part of language as much as tense, aspect, definiteness and specificity....)

Comment: Incidentally, your statement that "nuance/context 'markers' would hurt any system (use adverbials?)" is curious. Are you suggesting that languages other than English would have different trees? Even Japanese has evidentials and particles that mark the speaker's estimation of the truth value of his/her statements. How does GG treat them? Where do よ and ね go in the tree?

Comment: They seem adverbial, but they may merely affect the strength of connections, rather than add new data; or they may be stored as separate contextual data that is only temporally associated.  (I only know rudiments of Japanese.)

Comment: よ and ね are sentence-final particles. Because they have traditionally been ignored in Western grammar since ancient times they appear to be ignored in GG too. 'Adding new data' (foregrounding new information) is not the sole function of language, and the scope of grammatical theory should not be determined by a priori assumptions that it is. Your comments highlight one of the problems with GG: it appears to be determined by a small group of languages that linguists happen to know.

Comment: The sole function of language is to move data from one mind to another.  To understand why the channel is formatted a certain way, we need to explore how the data is represented in each mind.  That all the (non-redundant) data exists somewhere in the brain is a valid assumption.  That it fits a certain scaffold is not a proof, but allows a working model.  All models that work are worthy of exploration.  The one that matches the brain will (only) be of historic interest.

Comment: At any rate, this is not the place to discuss the pros and cons of GG. But your answer to the question simply brings into focus the various assumptions that lie behind the treatment of prepositions as head of PP (e.g., the sole function of language is to move data from one mind to another'). It's easy to justify a particular treatment when it's already been decided that it's 'correct' in terms of theory. Suffice it to say that I don't believe that 'The sole function of language is to move data from one mind to another'.

Comment: I should have mentioned *interjections* as being either adverbial or in a separate 'tree'.  Narrative data storage is only a partial (and new) use of the brain.  It probably uses methods that already existed for storing experience data.  I'd like to hear some other function of language (I'll admit artistic resonances).  Are you referring to internal dialogues?

Comment: Well, a lot depends on what you mean by 'data'. Had you said 'communication' your thinking might be easier to accept. But 'moving data'? Come on! And your premise narrows the scope of grammar down neatly to traditional Western grammar. Is language really made up of 'sentences'? Is there really no overly redundant data in the brain? You seem to be narrowing everything down to something you can fit in your tree structure model. Chomsky did something similar by excluding performance.

Comment: Data=information.  What else would the brain store?  Communication=the **moving** of that data.  Language data is predicates, which are filed by subject.  Dialogue fragments are just elided sentences.  Information storage has a cost.  Evolution minimizes costs unless a purpose is served.  I try harder to not discard data -- I try to see the net (storage) despite the trees (communication).  I look for ways to temporize context (broaden its scope) to reduce redundancy.  I am still amazed how we maintain models of other peoples knowledge, so we know how *definite* we can be with each listener.

Comment: And I would be a fool to model **the** brain -- I try to model **a** brain, given the clues of language.

Comment: I don't really want to continue this discussion in this thread. It's simply too big. But your approach seems far too simplistic. You seem to want a silver bullet that can explain everything about language, and "moving data" is your killer explanation. But how do you handle humour? What are the "data" being conveyed here? What kind of datum is an appeal to emotions? Unless you can come up with a "data movement" model that is elastic enough to explain all communication, and detailed enough to cover all aspects of all languages, I just can't see much of interest here. Sorry.

Comment: Humor has nothing to do with communication.  It is the paradoxical juxtaposition of contrasting data.  You can experience humor without language, and you can communicate it many ways, including dead-pan.  The humor is in the data.  The same goes for emotion.  Yes, we store all kinds of data besides the words we hear or see, so we know who said what and with what manner, but a faithful 'recording' is short term -- long term memory is highly pruned.

Comment: "Humor has nothing to do with communication." Well that is rather dogmatic. And you are working with a very narrow definition of communication. What else do you want to prune away? That is why I don't think there is anything here. You define the scope of language to suit your own interpretation. I also challenge you to come up with a definition of 'sentence'. One that covers all languages, not just English.

Comment: There is plenty of humor 'about' communication, but any syntax *designed* to be humorous will hinder its use for general communication.  A sentence is the smallest packet that leaves no dangling links in the transferred data, given syntactic choices that may compress the packet -- A sentence may contain sub-packets which also satisfy the link constraint, but those sub-packets are not sentences because of syntactic choices which don't allow them to be moved to a separate sentence packet (those choices being made in order to reduce the overall size of the combined packet).

Comment: "those choices being made in order to reduce the overall size of the combined packet" -- I am curious about your model. What exactly are you aiming to do? What are you aiming to create?

Comment: 'Sentences' are surface structure, so they are model independent.  I'm just saying something like "A big dog ate my homework" is condensed from data representing 'one dog is big', 'I did have homework', and 'the dog did eat the homework'.

Comment: Well, good luck.